# Web application could not be started by the Phusion Passenger application server, ModuleNotFoundError - Django [SOLVED]

Tags: django, pip, passenger

when I install a third-site application from github with `pip install -e git+https://github.com/breduin/das.git#egg=django_ajax_selects`  my site doesn't start and the following error raises:

```
Web application could not be started by the Phusion Passenger application server.



/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py:26: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import sys, os, re, imp, threading, signal, traceback, socket, select, struct, logging, errno
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 369, in <module>
    app_module = load_app()
  File "/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 76, in load_app
    return imp.load_source('passenger_wsgi', startup_file)
  File "/opt/python/python-3.8.6/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/www/u1234567/data/www/mysite/passenger_wsgi.py", line 7, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/var/www/u1234567/data/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/var/www/u1234567/data/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/var/www/u1234567/data/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/var/www/u1234567/data/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/opt/python/python-3.8.6/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ajax_select'
```

In the directory `env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/`, where usually all the packages from PyPI are placed one can find the egg-file,
**django-ajax-selects.egg-link**

```
/var/www/u1234567/data/env/src/django-ajax-selects
.
```

The path is correct, the application django-ajax-selects is placed there.

Without this application from github and with other applications from PyPI my site starts ok.
It seems like server doesn't recognize egg-link or path, but I couldn't find out how to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

SO-effect, while writing the question I found the answer by myself: one needs to add the path to the package (which is in the egg-link file) in **passenger_wsgi.py**:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/u1234567/data/www/mysite/mysite')
sys.path.insert(1, '/var/www/u1234567/data/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages')
sys.path.insert(2, '/var/www/u1234567/data/env/src/django-ajax-selects')     #<---- this path
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```